# Start Android Wear Watchface from Activity

Tags: android-activity, android-service, wear-os, watchface

I am wondering if it's possible to start the Watchface Service from an activity?

I tried to start the service in the onCreate method of my activity but it does not show the Watchface:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CustomWatchFaceService);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

*update*
Here is the code for the WatchfaceService

```
public class CustomWatchFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
    private static final String TAG = "DigitalWatchFaceService";

    private static final Typeface BOLD_TYPEFACE =
            Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    private static final Typeface NORMAL_TYPEFACE =
            Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);

    private static final long NORMAL_UPDATE_RATE_MS = 500;
    private static final long MUTE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new Engine();
    }

    private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

        static final String COLON_STRING = ":";
        static final int MUTE_ALPHA = 100;
        static final int NORMAL_ALPHA = 255;
        static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;
        long mInteractiveUpdateRateMs = NORMAL_UPDATE_RATE_MS;

        final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                switch (message.what) {
                    case MSG_UPDATE_TIME:
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "updating time");
                        }
                        invalidate();
                        if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                            long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            long delayMs =
                                    mInteractiveUpdateRateMs - (timeMs % mInteractiveUpdateRateMs);
                            mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, delayMs);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };


        Paint mBackgroundPaint;
        Bitmap mBackgroundBitmap;
        Bitmap wifiIconOn;
        Bitmap wifiIconOff;
        Paint mDatePaint;
        Paint mNotificationPaint;
        Paint mNotificationMax;
        Paint mNotificationHigh;
        Paint mHourPaint;
        Paint mMinutePaint;
        Paint mSecondPaint;
        Paint mAmPmPaint;
        Paint mColonPaint;
        float mColonWidth;
        boolean mMute;

        Calendar mCalendar;
        Date mDate;
        SimpleDateFormat mDayOfWeekFormat;
        java.text.DateFormat mDateFormat;

        boolean mShouldDrawColons;
        float mXOffset;
        float mYOffset;
        float mLineHeight;

        int mInteractiveBackgroundColor =
                R.color.interactive_bg;
        int mInteractiveNotificationMax =
                R.color.notification_max;
        int mInteractiveNotificationHigh =
                R.color.notification_high;
        int mInteractiveNotificationColor =
                R.color.notification;
        int mInteractiveHourDigitsColor =
                R.color.interactive_time;
        int mInteractiveMinuteDigitsColor =
                R.color.interactive_time;
        int mInteractiveSecondDigitsColor =
                R.color.interactive_time;

        boolean mLowBitAmbient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            }
            super.onCreate(holder);
            Locale locale = new Locale("de");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


            setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(CustomWatchFaceService.this)
                    .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_VARIABLE)
                    .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                    .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                    .build());
            Resources resources = CustomWatchFaceService.this.getResources();
            mYOffset = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.digital_y_offset);
            mLineHeight = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.digital_line_height);


            setInteractiveColors();

            // Not sure why the text color needs to be set here again ... it should be set in setDefaultColors()!
            mDatePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.digital_date));
            mNotificationPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.notification));
            mNotificationMax.setColor(getColor(R.color.notification_max));
            mNotificationHigh.setColor(getColor(R.color.notification_high));

            mHourPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
            mMinutePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
            mSecondPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
            mColonPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));

            //Images should be loaded here so they can be called during the Draw Method
            wifiIconOn = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(CustomWatchFaceService.this.getResources(), R.drawable.wifi_on_small);
            wifiIconOff = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(CustomWatchFaceService.this.getResources(), R.drawable.wifi_off_small);
            mBackgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.customcart_logo_240_alpha);



            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mDate = new Date();
            initFormats();
        }

        public void setInteractiveColors() {
            mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
            mBackgroundPaint.setColor(getColor(mInteractiveBackgroundColor));
            mNotificationPaint = createTextPaint(mInteractiveNotificationColor);
            mNotificationMax = createTextPaint(mInteractiveNotificationMax);
            mNotificationHigh = createTextPaint(mInteractiveNotificationHigh);
            mDatePaint = createTextPaint(R.color.digital_date);
            mHourPaint = createTextPaint(mInteractiveHourDigitsColor, BOLD_TYPEFACE);
            mMinutePaint = createTextPaint(mInteractiveMinuteDigitsColor);
            mSecondPaint = createTextPaint(mInteractiveSecondDigitsColor);
            mColonPaint = createTextPaint(R.color.digital_colons);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private Paint createTextPaint(int defaultInteractiveColor) {
            return createTextPaint(defaultInteractiveColor, NORMAL_TYPEFACE);
        }

        private Paint createTextPaint(int defaultInteractiveColor, Typeface typeface) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(defaultInteractiveColor);
            paint.setTypeface(typeface);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            return paint;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVisibilityChanged: " + visible);
            }
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            updateTimer();
        }

        private void initFormats() {
            mDayOfWeekFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
            mDayOfWeekFormat.setCalendar(mCalendar);
            mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(CustomWatchFaceService.this);
            mDateFormat.setCalendar(mCalendar);
        }


        @Override
        public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplyWindowInsets: " + (insets.isRound() ? "round" : "square"));
            }
            super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

            // Load resources that have alternate values for round watches.
            Resources resources = CustomWatchFaceService.this.getResources();
            boolean isRound = insets.isRound();
            mXOffset = resources.getDimension(isRound
                    ? R.dimen.digital_x_offset_round : R.dimen.digital_x_offset);
            float textSize = resources.getDimension(isRound
                    ? R.dimen.digital_text_size_round : R.dimen.digital_text_size);
            float notificationTextSize = resources.getDimension(isRound
                    ? R.dimen.notification_text_size : R.dimen.notification_text_size);

            mDatePaint.setTextSize(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.digital_date_text_size));

            mHourPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mMinutePaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mSecondPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mColonPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mNotificationPaint.setTextSize(notificationTextSize);

            mColonWidth = mColonPaint.measureText(COLON_STRING);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
            super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);

            boolean burnInProtection = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION, false);
            mHourPaint.setTypeface(burnInProtection ? NORMAL_TYPEFACE : BOLD_TYPEFACE);

            mLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);

            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPropertiesChanged: burn-in protection = " + burnInProtection
                        + ", low-bit ambient = " + mLowBitAmbient);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeTick() {
            super.onTimeTick();
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTimeTick: ambient = " + isInAmbientMode());
            }
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
            super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
            if (!isInAmbientMode()) {
                mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
                mBackgroundPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_bg));
                mDatePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.digital_date));
                mHourPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
                mMinutePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
                mSecondPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
                mColonPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.interactive_time));
            }
            else {
                mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
                mBackgroundPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.ambient_bg));
                mDatePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.digital_date));
                mHourPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.ambient_time));
                mMinutePaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.ambient_time));
                mSecondPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.ambient_time));
                mColonPaint.setColor(getColor(R.color.ambient_time));
            }

            //Log.d("XXX", "onAmbientModeChanged: " + inAmbientMode);


            if (mLowBitAmbient) {
                boolean antiAlias = !inAmbientMode;
                mDatePaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
                mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
                mMinutePaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
                mSecondPaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
                mAmPmPaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
                mColonPaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
            }
            invalidate();

            // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're in ambient mode (as well
            // as whether we're visible), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterruptionFilterChanged(int interruptionFilter) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterruptionFilterChanged: " + interruptionFilter);
            }
            super.onInterruptionFilterChanged(interruptionFilter);

            boolean inMuteMode = interruptionFilter == WatchFaceService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE;
            // We only need to update once a minute in mute mode.
            setInteractiveUpdateRateMs(inMuteMode ? MUTE_UPDATE_RATE_MS : NORMAL_UPDATE_RATE_MS);

            if (mMute != inMuteMode) {
                mMute = inMuteMode;
                int alpha = inMuteMode ? MUTE_ALPHA : NORMAL_ALPHA;
                mDatePaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                mHourPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                mMinutePaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                mColonPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                mAmPmPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        public void setInteractiveUpdateRateMs(long updateRateMs) {
            if (updateRateMs == mInteractiveUpdateRateMs) {
                return;
            }
            mInteractiveUpdateRateMs = updateRateMs;

            // Stop and restart the timer so the new update rate takes effect immediately.
            if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                updateTimer();
            }
        }

        private String formatTwoDigitNumber(int hour) {
            return String.format("%02d", hour);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();


            int width = bounds.width();
            int height = bounds.height();
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(now);
            mDate.setTime(now);
            boolean is24Hour = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(CustomWatchFaceService.this);

            // Draw the background.
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height(), mBackgroundPaint);

            //Draw the background Image
            if (mBackgroundBitmap == null
                    || mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth() != width
                    || mBackgroundBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
                mBackgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap,
                        width, height, true /* filter */);

            }
            //Log.d("XXX", "Width: "+ mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth() + "Height: "+mBackgroundBitmap.getHeight() );


            if (isInAmbientMode() && (mLowBitAmbient)) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if (isInAmbientMode()) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, 0, 0, mBackgroundPaint);
            }



            // Show colons for the first half of each second so the colons blink on when the time updates.
            mShouldDrawColons = (System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) < 500;



            // Draw the hours.
            float x = mXOffset;
            String hourString;
            if (is24Hour) {
                hourString = formatTwoDigitNumber(mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            } else {
                int hour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                if (hour == 0) {
                    hour = 12;
                }
                hourString = String.valueOf(hour);
            }
            canvas.drawText(hourString, x, mYOffset, mHourPaint);
            x += mHourPaint.measureText(hourString);

            // In ambient and mute modes, always draw the first colon. Otherwise, draw the
            // first colon for the first half of each second.
            if (isInAmbientMode() || mMute || mShouldDrawColons) {
                canvas.drawText(COLON_STRING, x, mYOffset, mColonPaint);
            }
            x += mColonWidth;

            // Draw the minutes.
            String minuteString = formatTwoDigitNumber(mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            canvas.drawText(minuteString, x, mYOffset, mMinutePaint);
            x += mMinutePaint.measureText(minuteString);

            // In unmuted interactive mode, draw a second blinking colon followed by the seconds.
            // Otherwise, if we're in 12-hour mode, draw AM/PM
            if (!isInAmbientMode() && !mMute) {
                if (mShouldDrawColons) {
                    canvas.drawText(COLON_STRING, x, mYOffset, mColonPaint);
                }
                x += mColonWidth;
                canvas.drawText(formatTwoDigitNumber(
                        mCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)), x, mYOffset, mSecondPaint);
            } else if (!is24Hour) {
                x += mColonWidth;

            }

            // Only render the day of week and date if there is no peek card, so they do not bleed
            // into each other in ambient mode.
            if (getPeekCardPosition().isEmpty()) {
                // Day of week
                canvas.drawText(
                        mDayOfWeekFormat.format(mDate),
                        mXOffset, mYOffset + mLineHeight, mDatePaint);
                // Date
                canvas.drawText(
                        mDateFormat.format(mDate),
                        mXOffset, mYOffset + mLineHeight * 2, mDatePaint);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Starts the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer if it should be running and isn't currently
         * or stops it if it shouldn't be running but currently is.
         */
        private void updateTimer() {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateTimer");
            }
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer should be running. The timer should
         * only run when we're visible and in interactive mode.
         */
        private boolean shouldTimerBeRunning() {
            return isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CustomWatchFaceService); by Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CustomWatchFaceService.class);

Comment: Same result. The onCreate or onDraw method from the Watchfaceservice is not called.

Comment: put your watchfaceservice class code here

Comment: When you say start - do you mean setting the watch face?

Comment: Yes, I can only "start" the watchface by selecting it from the watchface browser.

Comment: The Watchface of course "starts" as well when I go into ambient mode when the activity is open from where I want to go into the Watchface directly.

Comment: I did the other way around. Have you added the service to your android manifest?

Comment: vote for this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960014/starting-an-activity-from-android-wear-watchface